# Python - indexing an element in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, object

I am a new Python programmer and trying some stuff out. I want to create a list of strings and loop through my list to check the size of each element, if the size is greater than 5, then I will change that string into an uppercase string. I am stuck on how to access that element. Below is some of the code that I have written. Thank you in advance!

```
lis = ['heeeeellllooo','world','low','higggghhh']
for elem in list:
  if len(lis[elem]) > 5:
    list[elem].upper()
```

Comment: `for elem in list` is trying to iterate over the `list` class. If you change that to `for elem in lis` to iterate over the instance you just created, each `elem` is one of the strings, like `'world'`, so `lis[elem]` is meaningless. That's why you need `enumerate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use  a [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`ternary operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
In [16]: lis = ['heeeeellllooo','world','low','higggghhh']

In [17]: [x.upper() if len(x)>5 else x for x in lis] # this is a new list

Out[17]: ['HEEEEELLLLOOO', 'world', 'low', 'HIGGGGHHH']
```

You can also use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), `enumerate` returns a `tuple` whole first item is the index of the element and the second item is  the element itself.

This method modifies the original list.

```
In [18]: for index,elem in enumerate(lis):
   ....:     if len(elem)>5:
   ....:         lis[index]=elem.upper()  #access element by index
   ....:         

In [19]: lis
Out[19]: ['HEEEEELLLLOOO', 'world', 'low', 'HIGGGGHHH']
```

**[How are lists implemented?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented):**

> Python’s lists are really variable-length arrays, not Lisp-style
>   linked lists. The implementation uses a contiguous array of references
>   to other objects, and keeps a pointer to this array and the array’s
>   length in a list head structure.
>
> This makes indexing a list a[i] an operation whose cost is independent
>   of the size of the list or the value of the index.
>
> When items are appended or inserted, the array of references is
>   resized. Some cleverness is applied to improve the performance of
>   appending items repeatedly; when the array must be grown, some extra
>   space is allocated so the next few times don’t require an actual
>   resize.

Comment: Could you clarify what "In" and "out" mean? Thank you

Comment: This is the output from a from an interactive shell

Comment: Perfect, enumerate makes sense. Can you explain why it would not work without an index? or "enumerate" over "in".

Comment: @user1965106 list are arrays where whose elements can only be accessed by indexes.

Comment: +1 for giving both the immutable answer and the mutable one, and explaining how they work.

Answer (score 3):

`enumerate` is very useful, if you'd like to change it in place. 
Try this:

```
for idx, elem in enumerate(lis):
    if len(elem) > 5:
        list[idx] = elem.upper()
```

Comment: +1… But the variable is called `lis`, so this will try to enumerate and mutate the `list` class, which isn't going to work…

Comment: The OP's code has the same problem. It uses `lis` almost everywhere, except in `for elem in list`. So, not too surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to do what you were trying using a for loop.  Your code used two different variable names for the list: lis and list.  The variable elem is the item in the list, not the index.  To get the index, you need to use enumerate().  The solution shown by Ashwini Chaudhary is called a list comprehension and is a much better way to do this.

```
for i, elem in enumerate(lis):
  if len(elem) > 5:
    lis[i] = elem.upper()
```

Comment: So, this is identical to the answer provided by dave 7 minutes ago, but with the addition of suggesting that Ashwini Chaudhary's solution—which also contains the same code—is better. What's the point in writing this answer?

Comment: I started my answer before dave posted his and before Ashwini Chaudhary updated his answer.  I took time to answer the actual question that was asked and test it before posting it.  I then made sure to mention that the list comprehension was the better way.